# Git remote branch is ahead of the local branch. Then, when using `git pull`, I'm told that the local repository is "Already up to date."

Tags: git, git-pull

There is one additional file in my remote repository branch "v2". On my local repository branch "v2", `git status` states:

"Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit."

However, because I pushed this additional file (i.e. pushed the commit) from a different account on a different machine, the remote repository branch "v2" is ahead of origin/main by 2 commits. All I want to do is bring my local branch "v2" up-to-date so that it too is 2 commits ahead of origin/main, but, when I try to `git pull`, I'm told that it is "Already up to date."

I've tried `git fetch --all`, to another `git pull`, which didn't work. Then I tried `git reset --hard` to another `git pull`, which also didn't work.

Does anyone have any insight here?

Comment: Please be careful. Git doesn't push files. It pushes commits. `git push` should resolve the original error.

Comment: I've tried git push as well with the following error:


! [rejected]        HEAD -> v2 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/cdbrenner/cs642_pa1.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your v2 branch is incorrectly configure to track the main branch. Say

```
git branch -u main v2
```

and after that, pulling on v2 will work as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, but I don't fully understand it.

Apparently, `git pull` alone was attempting to pull from the main branch, even though I was using the command while on the v2 branch. Since the local v2 was ahead of the remote main, it would state that v2 was already up to date.

Finally, from the v2 branch, I commanded:

`git pull origin v2`

and this achieved the result of pulling the additional commit. Now I wonder if there is a way to configure a branch so that when commanding `git pull`, it will default to pulling from the remote branch that the local branch is connected to.

Comment: But this is why I asked for the information you have not provided. Clearly you have wrongly set the main branch as the upstream of your v2 local.

Comment: Added this as a new answer.